# Why does this Cypher query take too much time?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have

- 50K Post nodes
- 40K Tag nodes
- 125K TAGGED relationships (meaning average 2,5 tags per post)

in my graph and below query causes a "Java heap space" error.

```
match (p1:Post)-[r1:TAGGED]->(t:Tag)<-[r2:TAGGED]-(p2:Post)
return p1.Title, count(r1), p2.Title, count(r2)
limit 10
```

What I expected was some repeated rows depending on number of shared tags. I was not sure how `limit` would work (stop after first 10 posts or tags). But, since I have `limit 10` I did not expect this query to traverse all the graph. It seems like it does.

### UPDATE 1

With a few changes, Christophe Willemsen's query returns 10 rows in 15 sec.

```
// I need label for the otherPost because Users are also TAGGED
MATCH (post:Post)-[:TAGGED]->(t)<-[:TAGGED]-(otherPost:Post) 
RETURN post.Title, count(t) as cnt, otherPost.Title
// ORDER BY cnt DESC // for now I do not need this
LIMIT 10;
```

I thought "ORDER BY" clause may cause traversal of all possible paths so I removed the clause but it is still 15 sec. It is also 15 sec. when I make the limit value 1 or 1000 without sorting.

What I expect from Neo4j was: "Start from any `Post` node, then jump to its Tags and find otherPosts that are tagged with the same tag. When there are 10 found stop traversing and return the results." I am pretty sure it is not doing this.

To make my expectation clear, assume that graph is this small and we use `Limit 3` in the cypher query.

```
p1 - [t1, t2, t3] // Post1 is tagged with t1, t2 and t3
p2 - [t2, t3, t4]
p3 - [t3, t4, t5]
```

What I expect is:

- Start form p1 (or any Post node)
- Jump to t1
- No other posts are tagged with t1
- Jump to t2
- p2 is tagged with t2 (1 of 3)
- No other posts are tagged with t2
- Jump to t3
- p2 is tagged with t3 (2 of 3)
- p3 is tagged with t3 (3 of 3)
- we reached the limit, break

But, it seems like Limit is applied after traversing all data.

So, my question is now: Did Neo4j found all the matches and returned 10 of them or did it stop searching after first 10 matches? And of course, Why?

### UPDATE 2

After helpful answers I managed to decrease the scope of my question so I tried below queries.

```
// 3 sec.
MATCH (p:Post)-[:TAGGED]->(t:Tag)
RETURN p.Title, count(t)
LIMIT 1; 

// 3 sec.
MATCH (p:Post)-[:TAGGED]->(t:Tag)
RETURN p.Title, count(t)
LIMIT 1000; 

// 100 ms.
MATCH (p:Post)-[:TAGGED]->(t:Tag)
RETURN p.Title, t.Name
LIMIT 1; 

// 150 ms.
MATCH (p:Post)-[:TAGGED]->(t:Tag)
RETURN p.Title, t.Name
LIMIT 1000;
```

So, I still do not know why but, using aggregation methods (I tried `collect(t.Name)` instead of `count`) breaks the expected (at least my expectations :) behaviour of `limit` functionality.

Comment: could you please describe the query in natural language?

Comment: I did not write the query for getting some meaningful data. I just tried to fetch first ten posts those are sharing at least one tag with another post. After seeing that result I was planning to sort the data according to number of shared tags.

Comment: have you tried this on 2.2.0-RC1 ? 2.2 has a much improved query optimizer that might help here.

Answer (score 6):

This query will result in a global graph lookup, at least for neo4j 2.1.7 and below.

I would first matching the nodes and then expanding the path

```
MATCH (post:Post)
MATCH (post)-[:TAGS]->(t)<-[:TAGS]-(otherPost)
RETURN post, count(t) as cnt, otherPost
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

And this is the execution plan, as you can see by matching first the post nodes only (so labels index) it costs you only retrieving those and following relationships

```
ColumnFilter
  |
  +Top
    |
    +EagerAggregation
      |
      +Filter
        |
        +SimplePatternMatcher
          |
          +NodeByLabel

+----------------------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|             Operator |   Rows | DbHits |                                  Identifiers |                                                                                          Other |
+----------------------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|         ColumnFilter |     10 |      0 |                                              |                                                              keep columns post, cnt, otherPost |
|                  Top |     10 |      0 |                                              | {  AUTOINT0}; Cached(  INTERNAL_AGGREGATEc24f01bf-69cc-4bd9-9aed-be257028194b of type Integer) |
|     EagerAggregation |   9900 |      0 |                                              |                                                                                post, otherPost |
|               Filter | 134234 |      0 |                                              |                                                                NOT(  UNNAMED30 ==   UNNAMED43) |
| SimplePatternMatcher | 134234 |      0 | t,   UNNAMED43,   UNNAMED30, post, otherPost |                                                                                                |
|          NodeByLabel |    100 |    101 |                                   post, post |                                                                                          :Post |
+----------------------+--------+--------+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 101
```

And here a blog post explaining why I removed labels except for the first part of the query : http://graphaware.com/neo4j/2015/01/16/neo4j-graph-model-design-labels-versus-indexed-properties.html

Comment: Are you meaning then that you only want one post node in the beginning and not all ?

Comment: Yes, not all. Just start from any post. Of course, I expect it to continue with another post if traversal of tags of the initial post is ended before reaching the limit. ie. If limit were 5 in my small data example it should continue searching with tags of p2 find p2-p3 matches.

Comment: Is the query in your update the last query you tried ? Because the first part of the match is not splitted so it still results in a global graph lookup

Comment: Splitting was not changing duration, it was still 15 sec. BTW I think I found th reason for the full traversal. I think, it is because the `count` aggregation

Comment: You should not have a full traversal if the first match is not part of the first pattern. What is your execution plan with PROFILE ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73197/discussion-between-mehmet-atas-and-christophe-willemsen).

Answer (score 2):

What Christophe said **and**
Try to reduce the cardinality in between:

```
match (p1:Post)-[r1:TAGGED]->(t:Tag)
WITH tag, count(*) as freq, collect(distinct p1.Title) as posts
MATCH (tag)<-[r2:TAGGED]-(p2:Post)
return posts, freq, p2.Title, count(r2)
limit 10
```